# How to check the scope of a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scope

Is there a programmatic way to determine the scope of a variable in Powershell? After reading the [about_scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6) page it states to use [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable?view=powershell-6), but in testing it seems the variable objects look the same, excepting the `Name` and `Value`:

```
# Script variable
$cool = 'nice'
Get-Variable cool | Select * # => Options     : None
                             #    Value       : nice
                             #    Name        : nice
                             #    Description : 
                             #    Visibility  : Public
                             #    Module      : 
                             #    ModuleName  : 
                             #    Attributes  : {}

# Child variable
function Test-Function {
  $dude = 'sweet'
  Get-Variable dude | Select-Object *
}
Test-Function # => Options     : None
              #    Value       : sweet
              #    Name        : dude
              #    Description :
              #    Visibility  : Public
              #    Module      :
              #    ModuleName  :
              #    Attributes  : {}
```

What I was thinking of doing was doing `Get-Variable -Scope 0` (or `1`) to check if a variable is declared in the current or parent scope, or against the `Global`, `Local`, or `Script` scopes, then finding the variable name in each scope starting with the lowest possible scope first, but I'm hoping there is a more graceful method of finding out where a variable was declared in a Powershell session.

Comment: What... are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: _"then finding the variable name in each scope starting with the lowest possible scope first"_: do you mean something like determining if `$global:dude`, `$local:dude` and `$script:dude` are all defined, and preferentially using `script`'s value over `local`'s over `global`'s? It seems that that would only happen if you redefined the a variable again yourself that happens to collide with a higher scope's... Also unless you explicitly ask for a higher scope's name, you'll get your current scope's anyway.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking if there is a graceful way to check the scopes a variable was defined in, regardless of how many scopes it has been defined in.

Comment: Perhaps this is merely a lack of imagination and Posh-fu, but I can't think of a way other than simply looking for null values in progressively-ascending scopes.

Comment: Yeah that's where I landed too. Glad I'm not off base on this.

Comment: Right, but _why_ - even if you could, what would be the use of this information?

Answer (score 1):

We can not see how many scope we have straight. Main idea is that we have scope count no more then Get-PSCallStack count plus 3.

```
Function Get-VariableScope {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(        
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $True, Position = 0, HelpMessage = "Variable name." )]
        [string] $VariableName,
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $false, Position = 1, HelpMessage = "Variable value.", ParameterSetName = 'Variable' )]
        $VariableValue,
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $false, Position = 2, HelpMessage = "Scope list.", ParameterSetName = 'Scope array' )]
        [switch] $ScopeArray
    )
    $Result = $null

    $ScopeList = (0..( ( Get-PSCallStack ).count + 2 ))
    $VariableScopeArray = @()
    foreach ( $Scope in $ScopeList ){
        try{
            $Res = Get-Variable -Name $VariableName -Scope $Scope -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
            if ( $Res ){
                $Res | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Scope' -NotePropertyValue $Scope
                $VariableScopeArray += $Res
            }
        }
        Catch{ }
        
    }

    if ( $ScopeArray ){
        $Result = $VariableScopeArray
    }
    else {
        $Result = ( $VariableScopeArray | Where-Object { $_.value -eq $VariableValue } ).scope
    }

    return $Result
}
```

To see the variable $Name scope number call `Get-VariableScope -VariableName 'name' -VariableValue $Name`
To see all scopes variable in, call `Get-VariableScope -VariableName 'name' -ScopeArray`